# homomorphism between $K = \langle u,v \mid u^2 = 1, v^4 =1, uv=vu\rangle$ and $ \mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $K = \langle u,v \mid u^2 = 1, v^4 =1, uv=vu\rangle$ be a group. Is there a homomorphism between K and $ \mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: Yes, in both directions. It is not that hard to guess what it should be.

Comment: Note that $K$ is the group $C_2 \times C_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $uv = vu$ tells you that your group is commutative. Therefore, every element $g$ can be written as $u^m v^n$ for some integer powers $m$ and $n$. In order to define a homomorphism $\varphi$, then, it will be enough to give the values of $\varphi$ only for $u$ and $v$, and then automatically $\varphi (g) = \big(\varphi (u)\big) ^m \big(\varphi (v)\big) ^n$.

You want $\varphi$ to take values in $\Bbb Z _4$; note that $\hat 0 = \varphi(1) =\varphi (u^2) = 2 \varphi (u)$, so the only possibilities are $\varphi(u) = \hat 0$ and $\varphi(u) = \hat 2$. For $v$, you have similarly $\hat 0 = \varphi(1) =\varphi (v^4) = 4 \varphi (v)$, but the equality $\hat 0 = 4 x$ is satisfied by every element of $\Bbb Z _4$, so it doesn't really matter what you choose for $\varphi(v)$, all four options are equally good.

To conclude, there are $2$ types of homomorphisms: the ones given by $\varphi (u^m v^n) = \hat n x$ and the ones given by $\varphi (u^m v^n) = \widehat {2m} + \hat n x$, with $x \in \Bbb Z _4$ arbitrary. There is a total of $8$ homomorphisms, $4$ in each type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Send $v$ to the generator of $\mathbb Z_4$.

Comment: That's not the only way. There are $8$ different homomorphisms.

Comment: I think that it is more important to specifiy where to send $u$, since $v$ can go anywhere.

Comment: Agreed. I should have said "and $u$ to $e$"; OP didn't ask for a list of all possible ones, but just whether there existed one. But my answer isn't very useful, and I'll delete shortly.